# Find the inductance of the coil by potential difference of the circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

> A coil is connected in series with a 10.0 k$\Omega$ resistor. An ideal 50.0 V battery is applied across the two devices, and the current reaches a value of 2.00 mA after 5.00 ms. Find the inductance of the coil.

I was solving this question and I used a formula to solve that but when I saw the true answer I didn't understand why I can't use my formula.

I tried to solve this question by considering the potential difference in the circuit. So I wrote:

$Ldi/dt+Ri=\epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ is the voltage of the battery.)

Why this equation doesn't give me the right answer? And when can I use this to solve a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is correct, but how you use it might not be correct. Assuming $\epsilon$ is constant voltage, solution to the above differential equation is

$$i(t) = \frac{\epsilon}{R} (1 - e^{-t/\tau})$$

where $\tau = L/R$ is the time constant of the circuit. From this it is straightforward to solve for $L$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just have a silly question. I know we must solve the differential equation but REALLY why can't we put the given current in the Ri part in my equation and calculate L directly?

Comment: @MahsaRahavi How do you know what is $di/dt$ at that moment?

Comment: Oh you're right. I was using the average difference of current instead of $di/dt$. Thanks for your help.